# Dataflow WindowIntoBatches WithShardedKey error (Python)

Tags: apache-beam, sharding, dataflow

we have a pipeline that we need to group messages by a dynamic key (based on the message) and make an external call.
The number of keys is unknown (We know the most frequent keys but new keys can appear as well).
Currently I have a fixed shard number per destination as follows

```
SHARDS_PER_DESTINATION = {
    "key_1": 60,
    "key_2": 40,
    "key_3": 40,
    "key_4": 40
    ...
}

def make_keys(elem):
    key = elem[0][ATTRIBUTES_FIELD][CODE_ATRIBUTE]
    num_shards = SHARDS_PER_DESTINATION.get(key, 10)  # Default to 10 shards
    t = ((key, random.randint(0, num_shards)), elem)
    return t
```

and this is my group by function

```
def expand(self, pcoll):
    return (pcoll
            | "Window" >> beam.WindowInto(beam.window.FixedWindows(self.max_waiting_time))
            | "Add timestamp to windowed elements" >> beam.ParDo(AddTimestamp())
            | "Add Key" >> beam.Map(make_keys)
            | "Groupby" >> beam.GroupByKey()
            )
```

and it works fine. Recently I found out about GroupIntoBatches.WithShardedKey so I am trying to use that.

```
def make_keys(elem):
    key = elem[0][ATTRIBUTES_FIELD][CODE_ATRIBUTE]
    t = (key, elem)
    return t

def expand(self, pcoll):
    return (pcoll
            | "Add timestamp" >> beam.ParDo(AddTimestamp())
            | "Add Key" >> beam.Map(make_keys)
            | "Shard key" >> beam.GroupIntoBatches.WithShardedKey(self.max_messages, self.max_waiting_time)
            )
```

but no matter what I tried I keep getting the following error

```
ValueError: ShardedKeyCoder[TupleCoder[FastPrimitivesCoder, FastPrimitivesCoder]] cannot be made deterministic for 'Window .... messages/Groupby/GroupIntoBatches/ParDo(_GroupIntoBatchesDoFn)'.
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of a Python Tuple is non-deterministic.

Try defining your tuple key into a `NamedTuple` and use the `RowCoder`.

```py
from typing import NamedTuple, Tuple

class MyKey(NamedTuple):
    key: str
    shard: int

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash((self.key, self.shard))

beam.coders.registry.register_coder(MyKey, beam.coders.RowCoder)

pcoll2 = pcoll | beam.Map(make_keys).with_output_types(Tuple[MyKey, MyObject])
```

Comment: Still the same error. If I change the key to a "static" one it works though ...
    def make_keys(elem):
        return "test_key"

Comment: Got it. I've updated my answer with NamedTuple and RowCoder. This should resolve the non-deterministic coder issue.